# DoesNotExist at /profiles/user-profile/ UserProfile matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to add a follow toggle but In my views I am getting error in matching query set. The userprofile exist in database than still I dont why is it happening. I hope you guess can figure out my mistake and tell me how can I fix it. I am learning django if you help me than that means a lot. I shall be thankful to you. if more code required for help than let me know i will share that.

```
class UserProfileFollowToggle(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.POST)
        user_to_toggle = request.POST.get('username')
        print(user_to_toggle)
        profile_ = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username__iexact=user_to_toggle)
        user = request.user
        if user in profile_.follower.all():
            profile_.follower.remove(user)
        else:
            profile_.follower.add(user)
        return redirect("/posts/list/")
```

follow_toggle.html:

```
<form class='form' method='POST' action={% url 'profiles:toggle' %}>
{% csrf_token %}
<input type='hidden' name='username' value="{% if username %}{{ username }} {% else %}{{ testuser }}{% endif %}">

<button class='btn {% if is_following %}btn-default {% else %}btn-primary{% endif %}'>{% if is_following %}Unfollow {% else %}Follow{% endif %}</button>
</form>
```

trace back

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/user-profile/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'accounts',
 'posts',
 'profiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\grapPub\grabpublic\profiles\views.py", line 31, in post
    profile_ = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username__iexact=user_to_toggle)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 415, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /profiles/user-profile/
Exception Value: UserProfile matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Are you sure the POST request contains a `username` parameter?

Comment: Yes. You can see. I have added form template in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will render with a space at the end. The template should thus look like:

```
#                                                                 no space ↓
<input type='hidden' name='username' value="{% if username %}{{ username }}{% else %}{{ testuser }}{% endif %}">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't know about this before that spacing this much matters in templates. Thanks again.

Comment: I need a little more help related to this thing can you me? . `def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
            context = super(UserProfileDetailView,self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
            
            is_following = False
            # print(user,'this is')
            # print(user.userprofile.follower.all())

            if self.user in self.request.user.userprofile.follower.all():
                is_following = True
            context["is_following"] = is_following
            return context`

Comment: in the condition I am trying to check if a particular user is inside the list of user follower list or not. But That `self.user` in if condition raising an error that **'UserProfileDetailView' object has no attribute 'user'**

Comment: @FlashMaddy: `self.user` does not make much sense since there is indeed no user attribute. I think it might be better however to ask a new question, and include all the relevant details (for example the source code of the view), since right now it is hard to follow what you are doing.

Comment: Well I have just asked that question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64299707/attributeerror-at-profiles-using-14-userprofiledetailview-object-has-no-attr)

Comment: VA Onsem I have question about django please check and maybe you can fix that error. The link of that question is given on the upper comment of this comment

Comment: @FlashMaddy: it looks like this link is deleted?

Comment: now check this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303253/generic-detail-view-userprofiledetailview-must-be-called-with-either-an-object-p/64310557?noredirect=1#comment113748471_64310557)